# Ударение в прилагательном «чудское»

Tags: орфоэпия

У С. Алексеева есть книга "Чудские копи". Речь там идет о мифическом народе "чудь белоглазая". Но вот как правильно поставить ударение: ч**у**дские или чудск**и**е? И, опять же, Ч**у**дское или Чудск**о**е озеро?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

От существительного ЧУДЬ образуется прилагательное чудскОй. Соответственно: "ЧудскИе копи", ЧудскОе озеро.

Answer (score 1):

[**ЧУДСКО́Й**](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ogegova/267994/%D0%A7%D0%A3%D0%94%D0%A1%D0%9A%D0%9E%D0%99), -ая, -ое.
1. см. чудь.
2. Относящийся к чуди, к их языкам, образу жизни, культуре, а также к территории их проживания, её внутреннему устройству, истории; такой, как у чуди.
Чудск**и**е племена. Чудск**о**е озеро.

*История свидетельствует, что рудные месторождения, в районе которых строились уральские заводы, а вслед за ними и города, были отмечены чудск**и**ми метками.*

Чудской снеток, чудская ряпушка, чудское городище, Чудская битва (Ледовое побоище).